# Hangouts Google Play Services problem

Tags: google-hangouts, google-play-services

Everytime I update hangouts I get this message whenever I open the app: "unkown issue with google play services". What is the cause of this problem? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be caused by a old version of play services.

To update the version manually open [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) link on your android device and click update if there is an update.

Hope this solves your problem

===============================

## EDIT:

Hope this way works for you. Keep in mind that setting names can be different from brand to brand.

1. Go to Setting > Security > Device Administrators
2. Un-check Android Device Manager
3. Go to `apps` and uninstall updates to Google Play Services
4. Go to Hangouts, it should show a message saying that you need to 'update Google Play Services'. Click update.
5. After updating, Hangouts should not show the error message
6. Go back to Settings > Administrators and check Android Device Manager

Comment: I've updated google play services using the market  update but the problem still exist

Comment: I updated the answer above, to hav a better overview

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did that exactly the last time. I think I have to do this every time I update Hangouts and Google Play Services.